# How to add row in telerik radGridView dynamically?

Tags: silverlight, telerik

I am using Telerik RadGridView control. I want to add row in radGridView in runtime.
I use following code:

```
<telerikGrid:RadGridView x:Name="TopGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <telerikGrid:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerikGrid:GridViewComboBoxColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding FieldName}" Width="150" Header="Field Name"/>
        <telerikGrid:GridViewComboBoxColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Operator}" ItemsSource="{Binding OperatorList, Source={StaticResource OperatorModel}}" Width="150" Header="Operator"/>               
    </telerikGrid:RadGridView.Columns>            
</telerikGrid:RadGridView>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're using as far as a datasource, but generally speaking you'd be binding the RadGridView to some ItemsSource, then the source for the combo box columns would come from there.

For example, with an entity:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
}
```

Binding the RadGridView to the List would automatically generate rows for this, so adding a new entity to that list would generate a new row.  More info on how you're binding/populating the grid would help me give a more specific answer. :)